# Lost Teams button in new calendar event screen in desktop Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

When scheduling a new Outlook meeting, I used to have a button to make it a Teams call. Pressing the button would automatically populate the body with Team call info. Now I don't see this button anymore. It simply disappeared. Others in my org are not having this issue. I now have to use Calendar in Teams to schedule meetings which is not convenient. Any way to restore the button without reinstalling Outlook or Teams? TIA

Comment: Are you looking for [Teams Meeting](https://oit.uta.edu/utaremote/assets/Add_a_Teams_Link_to_an_Existing_Outlook_Meeting.pdf)?

Comment: Yep. That button disappeared.

Comment: Please follow the steps described in the article [Resolve issues with Teams Meeting add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/meetings/resolve-teams-meeting-add-in-issues) and let me know if any of the manipulations helped with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the solution as @JimmyYang-MSFT mentioned in this thread:

[Teams meeting button not showing up in outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/774867/teams-meeting-button-not-showing-up-in-outlook).

[image]